# How to prevent Excel VBA paste special values from changing data type from number/date to text

Tags: excel, vba, paste

I am encountering a problem where Excel VBA paste special values is changing the data type to text when it carries out the paste values operation, which then breaks downstream formulas that expect to see a number/date instead of text.

At a high level, the process I have is the following:

1. starting with functional worksheet, duplicate and rename it;
2. perform operations on the newly created sheet including copy, paste special values;
3. formulas that depend on the pasted data are now broken because data type has been changed to text.

The code that is doing the copy paste special values looks like this:

```
Workbooks("myFile.xlsm").Sheets(pageFocus).Range(refreshCopyRange).Copy

Workbooks("myFile.xlsm").Sheets(pageFocus).Range(pasteRange).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
```

Is there some kind of modifier or override to PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues) that will stop Excel VBA from changing the data type?

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with the information you provide.  Various types of numeric data remain numeric when I do the copy/paste special values code.  Please provide enough information to reproduce your problem.  I suggest you read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  The formatting of some of the entries may change, but they remain numeric and not TExt

Comment: Thank you Ron.  Turns out part of my problem is source database (via API) is inconsistent with data types returned for "dates."  Sometimes API call to the database returns number/date and for other fields it returns text.  I had found other discussion in the forum that led me to believe paste special values was to blame such as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28000600/excel-paste-special-using-values-only-also-copies-the-data-type-of-the-value-al ... however it was database issue mostly in my case.  So I made translation formulas after API that make it always number/date.

Comment: I would think that reference to NOT be a reliable source.  Note that it has two downvotes, and there is no marked answer in the thread.  With regard to varying formats coming from your API call, a frequent reason for that would be that the API dates are valid, but not in a format that is congruent with your Windows Regional Setting (eg mdy vs dmy). When that occurs, you get a mix of text that looks like dates, and real dates; the real dates will mostly be **incorrect**. eg: `6/2/2017` from the DB might be `2 Jun 2017` when it should really be `6 Feb 2017`  So be careful how you translate.

Comment: Thanks Ron.  I will investigate translation carefully.  I believe this database vendor was just inconsistent in defining data types but I appreciate your tip very much as that would be extremely ugly in my financial app to think I was using accurate dates if/when in fact I was mis-translating them unbeknownst to myself.  Don't think I am but will double check and thanks again!  Clearly you have seen a thing or two in your coding days :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a second paste command for formatting:

```
Workbooks("myFile.xlsm").Sheets(pageFocus).Range(pasteRange).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Workbooks("myFile.xlsm").Sheets(pageFocus).Range(pasteRange).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
```

Here is a sample:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b593e52c-910c-4d24-b738-65878fe8a50d/how-to-copypaste-range-values-and-formats?forum=exceldev

Comment: Thanks Bookeater and Tim Williams - I believe your solutions can work also, along the same lines as Datatoo's suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
            xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: I am still testing but I believe this works -- thank you very much datatoo!